# Static file not being served from second project

Tags: global-variables, asp.net-core-6.0, static-classes

I have 2 startup projects:

- TB-GUI
- TB-WPS

both are webprojects.

Each has a static file

- TBGlobalSettings.cs
- WPSGlobalSettings.cs

At the startup both are properly initialized. The problem is when I try to access WPSGlobalSettings.ToolboxConnString later from the controller it is null.

**Controller.cs**

```
using (var m_Connection = new 
NpgsqlConnection(WPSGlobalSettings.ToolboxConnString.ConnectionString))
{
    //...some code
}
```

TBGlobalSettings however is always available.

I have also installed package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles in TBWPS project.

Any solution for this? (I am also interested in the why of this behaviour)

**WPSGlobalSettings.cs**

```
public static class WPSGlobalSettings
{
    
     
     private static readonly string ToolboxDatabaseName = GetValue<string>("tbdatabasename", "db");
     public static NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder ToolboxConnString = build_conn_str(ToolboxDatabaseName);

    

    private static IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    internal static void Configure(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    private static T GetValue<T>(string key, string prefix = Prefix)
     {
         string entry = string.Format("{0}:{1}", prefix, key);

    var value = Startup.WPSStaticConfig.GetValue<string>(entry);

    }



    //...other code...


    }
```

At startup these values are being filled/initialized.

When called from the controller, these values are null and the debugger goes to initialize them once more, therefore it crashes at the following line as WPSStaticConfig is also null

```
var value = Startup.WPSStaticConfig.GetValue<string>(entry);
```

**Startup.cs (TB-WPS)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        WPSStaticConfig = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public static IConfiguration WPSStaticConfig { get; private set; }

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        WPSGlobalSettings.Configure(env);
        ...

    }
```

TB-WPS is my secondary startup project where this issue is happening, the main mvc project (with UI) TB-GUI is implemented exactly same way and doesnt have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you could show your model and how you bind the connect string

you could try  as below:

```
configuration.GetSection("xxxxx").Bind(WPSGlobalSettings.ToolboxConnString);
```

Model class:

```
public static class WPSGlobalSettings
  {
    public static ToolboxConnString ToolboxConnString { get; set; } = new ToolboxConnString();//need instanced
  }
public class ToolboxConnString
{
 public string ConnectionString{get;set;}
 ........
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added my code too..It may give more clarity